# Set value of checkbox using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my jsp code with checkboxes

```
  <div class="col-md-2 right2 fon">
    <h6>Clinical Practice/Procedure</h6>
       <hr>
            <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalStat" id="clinicalStat" value="0"></p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0">Documentation</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalMiss" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0">Missing Files</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalPol" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0" > Policy not available</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalMed" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0" > Medical records unavailable</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalCon" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0" > Confidentiality</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalProc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0">Procedures not followed</p>
            <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalVals" id="clinicalVals" value="0"></p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)" > Other (Specify)</p>
            <p><input type="text2" id="text" name="incidentClassClinicalVal"  disabled="disabled" style="width: 92%"></p>
    </div>
```

I want to get value of the selected checkbox with alert. I am storing that value in `checked1` and I want to pass the value of `checked1` to another variable `checkedval`. When I try to `alert` the `checkedval` it shows me with the error `"undefined"`

The initial value of the checkbox is `0`. How to change its value to `1` when we click on it?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function()
    {
         //alert(" you checked");
         if(this.checked)
             {

             var checked1=document.getElementById('clinicalDoc').value;
             alert("The value for selected checkbox = "+checked1);

             var checkedval=$("#checked1").val('1');
              alert("checkedval="+checkedval);
               }
    });
```

Comment: Id should be unique.

Comment: @iam getting checked1 value but when iam passing to another variable to checkedval it showing me undefined

Comment: 1. id need to be unique. 2. don't mix jQuery/javascript both, use either-one completely.3. i am unable to see any element in your code having id `checked1`.Also all values of the check-boxes are 0 so how you gona distinguish which check-box is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` should be `unique`. The solution is to use `this` keyword which represents a reference to the current object.

As  @Alive to Die suggested, you should use only jQuery or Javascript, use either-one completely.

If you want to check if `checkbox` is checked you can use **jQuery** `is` function.

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
   //code
}
```

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
     //alert(" you checked");
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
         var checked1=$(this).val();
         alert("The value for selected checkbox = "+checked1);
         $(this).val('1');
         alert("checkedval="+$(this).val());
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 right2 fon">
  <h6>Clinical Practice/Procedure</h6>
     <hr>
      <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalStat" id="clinicalStat" value="0"></p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" value="0">Documentation</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalMiss" class="clinicalCheck"
      value="0">Missing Files</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalPol" class="clinicalCheck"
      value="0" > Policy not available</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalMed" class="clinicalCheck"
      value="0" > Medical records unavailable</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalCon" class="clinicalCheck"
      value="0" > Confidentiality</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalProc" class="clinicalCheck"
      value="0">Procedures not followed</p>
      <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalVals" id="clinicalVals" value="0"></p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)" > Other (Specify)</p>
      <p><input type="text2" id="text" name="incidentClassClinicalVal"  disabled="disabled" style="width: 92%"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: `val('1')` can be replaced as `val(+this.checked)` as on unchecking, it should go back to `0`

Comment: @aenugulakarthik You state ids should be unique, then you propagate the incorrect code.

Comment: @aenugulakarthik, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai  remove all common ids from your HTML.it will lead to ambigutiy for future visitors (As you siad that id need to be unique but still have common id's in your HTML)

Comment: What's the problem ? @aenugulakarthik

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai some problem in getting checked value to frontend